# withFormat closure is not sending response based on ACCEPT header

Tags: javascript, grails, mime-types

I'm trying the `withFormat` closure in grails. I've got the following in my action:

```
    if (myInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            withFormat {
                html {redirect(action: "list") }
                js {render "alert('came here')"}
            }

    }
```

As I understand the withFormat closure: If the `ACCEPT` header is `text/javascript` then it will only render the alert and if it is `['text/html','application/xhtml+xml']` then it will redirect to `list` action. However, in my case it is always rendering the `list` action.

I'm using REST Console in Chrome and here are the details of my request header:

```
Accept: text/javascript
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: chrome-extension: //rest-console-id
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
```

And here are the response headers:

```
Status Code: 200
Date: Fri, 10 May 2013 14:45:18 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

The response body is always coming back as HTML whereas I'm expecting `JS`

The mime types also seem correct in `config.groovy`

```
grails.mime.types = [
    all:           '*/*',
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]
```

What am I doing wrong here??

After some testing I found out that whichever closure comes first is taking precedence. If i have:

```
        withFormat {
            js {render "alert('came here')"}
            html {redirect(action: "list") }
        }
```

then always the JS is being rendered even if I an testing the application from browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grails.mime.use.accept.header = true` setting is required in `Config.groovy`. Do you have this set?

Refer the bottom of [withFormat](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/withFormat.html) page.

Comment: damnit! that was it. Now the response body is rendering the alert when ACCEPT header is `text/javascript`. However, Response `content-type` is still `text/html'. Is that a matter of concern?

Comment: Thats normal you can change your contentType in render using the contentType: 'text/javascript' property

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Dragged away for lunch. @davydotcom is correct. you can use something like `render(status: 200, contentType: 'text/javascript', text: "your text here")`. Also note, `text/javascript` is obsolete you can use `application/javascript` for cross browser compatibility.